# Custom one annotation on MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I fill my map with `MKPLaceMark`, with a specific address, these mark correspond to a meeting.

I'm trying to custom one placemark that corresponds to the next meeting.

Here is my code:

```
// Function to add all pin corresponding to all meeting.
- (void) addAllPins {
    _myMap.delegate = self;

    // Get all key of meeting
    NSArray* allKey = [[VSDataProvider sharedManager].startEvents allKeys];

    for (NSDate *date in allKey) {
        for (FFEvent *event in [[VSDataProvider sharedManager].startEvents objectForKey:date]) {

            // Retrieve with CLGeocoder the latitude and longitude with address of event
            NSString *localisation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@",event.street,event.zipCode,event.city,event.country];

            CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
            [geocoder geocodeAddressString:localisation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                    CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                    MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                    [arrayWithAllLocation addObject:place];
                    [self addPinWithTitle:event.street AndCoordinateLongitude:place.coordinate.longitude AndCoordinateLatitude:place.coordinate.latitude];
                }

                [self getCoordinateNexEvent:^{
                    for (MKPlacemark *mark in arrayWithAllLocation) {
                        if (mark.coordinate.latitude ==  _coordinateNextEvent.latitude && mark.coordinate.longitude == _coordinateNextEvent.longitude) {
                            MKAnnotationView *test = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:mark reuseIdentifier:@"nextEvent"];
                            test.annotation = mark;
                            test.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Meeting.png"];
                            [_myMap addAnnotation:test.annotation]; 
                        }
                    }
                }];
            }];
        }
    }
}

// Retrieve coordinate for the next meeting
- (void) getCoordinateNexEvent :(void (^)(void))afterAll {
    FFEvent *event = [VSDataProvider sharedManager].nextEvent;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    NSString *localisation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@",event.street,event.zipCode,event.city,event.country];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:localisation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
            _coordinateNextEvent.latitude = placemark.coordinate.latitude;
            _coordinateNextEvent.longitude = placemark.coordinate.longitude;
        }

        afterAll();
    }];
}

// This method add a Pin with the title and coordinate
- (void) addPinWithTitle : (NSString*)title AndCoordinateLongitude : (double)coordinateLongitude AndCoordinateLatitude : (double)coordinateLatitue {
    MKPointAnnotation *mapPin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinateLatitue, coordinateLongitude);
    mapPin.title = title;
    mapPin.coordinate = coordinate;
    [self.myMap addAnnotation:mapPin];
}

- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {    
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    span.latitudeDelta = 0.5;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.5;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;

    [_myMap setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

When I use

```
- (MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    __block MKAnnotationView *annotationWithNextEvent;

    annotationWithNextEvent = (MKAnnotationView*) [_myMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"nextEventAnnotation"];

    if (!annotationWithNextEvent) {

        annotationWithNextEvent = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:placemark reuseIdentifier:@"nextEventAnnotation"];
    }
    annotationWithNextEvent.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Meeting.png"];
    annotationWithNextEvent.annotation = annotation;
    return annotationWithNextEvent;
}
```

all annotations are a image, I don't want this.

I hope that I'm clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create subclass for it like the following:

```
@interface MeetingPointAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *customData;
@end
```

And then check for it:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MeetingPointAnnotation class]]) {
        __block MKAnnotationView *annotationWithNextEvent;
        annotationWithNextEvent = (MKAnnotationView*) [_myMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"nextEventAnnotation"];
        
        if (!annotationWithNextEvent) {
            annotationWithNextEvent = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:placemark reuseIdentifier:@"nextEventAnnotation"];
        }
        
        annotationWithNextEvent.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Meeting.png"];
        annotationWithNextEvent.annotation = annotation;
        return annotationWithNextEvent;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This will customize only that type of annotation

Also your code may have issues with `CLGeocoder` because it may potentially use it a lot. Read from the documentation:

> Applications should be conscious of how they use geocoding. Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. (When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder returns an error object with the value kCLErrorNetwork to the associated completion handler.) Here are some rules of thumb for using this class effectively:
>
> - Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action.
> - If the user performs multiple actions that involve geocoding the same location, reuse the results from the initial geocoding request instead of starting individual requests for each action.
> - When you want to update the user’s current location automatically (such as when the user is moving), issue new geocoding requests only when the user has moved a significant distance and after a reasonable amount of time has passed. For example, in a typical situation, you should not send more than one geocoding request per minute.
> - Do not start a geocoding request at a time when the user will not see the results immediately. For example, do not start a request if your application is inactive or in the background.